# Writing a Python pdfrw PdfReader object to an array of bytes / filestream

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdf-form, pdfrw

I'm currently working on a simple proof of concept for a pdf-editor application. The example is supposed to be a simplified python script showcasing how we could use the pdfrw library to edit PDF files with forms in them.

So, here's the issue. **I'm not interested in writing the edited PDF to a file.**
The idea is that file opening and closing is going to most likely be handled by external code and so I want all the edits in my files to be done in memory. I don't want to write the edited filestream to a local file.

Let me specify what I mean by this. I currently have a piece of code like this:

```py
class FormFiller:

    def __fill_pdf__(input_pdf_filestream : bytes, data_dict : dict):
        template_pdf : pdfrw.PdfReader = pdfrw.PdfReader(input_pdf_filestream)
            # <some editing magic here>
        return template_pdf

    def fillForm(self,mapper : FieldMapper):
        value_mapping : dict = mapper.getValues()
        filled_pdf : pdfrw.PdfReader = self.__fill_pdf__(self.filesteam, value_mapping)
        #<this point is crucial>

    def __init__(self, filestream : bytes):
        self.filesteam : bytes = filestream
```

So, as you see the FormFiller constructor receives an array of bytes. In fact, it's an `io.BytesIO` object. The `template_pdf` variable uses a `PdfReader` object from the pdfrw library. Now, when we get to the `#<this point is crucial>` marker, I have a `filled_pdf` variable which is a PdfReader object. I would like to convert it to a filestream (a bytes array, or an io.BytesIO object if you will), and return it in that form. **I don't want to write it to a file.** However, the writer class provided by pdfrw (pdfrw.PdfWriter) does not allow for such an operation. It only provides a `write(<filename>)` method, which saves the PdfReader object to a pdf output file.

How should I approach this? Do you recommend a workaround? Or perhaps I should use a completely different library to accomplish this?

Please help :-(

Comment: What happens if you create an empty `io.BytesIO` object and then `write(new_bytes_object)`?

Comment: Would you like me to write an "official" answer that explains the background a little bit?

Comment: Yes, please. I'll mark it as the correct one. Maybe it'll help out someone else in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save your altered PDF to memory in an object that can be passed around (instead of writing to a file), simply create an empty instance of [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

```
from io import BytesIO

new_bytes_object = BytesIO()
```

Then, use `pdfrw`'s `PdfWriter.write()` method to write your data to the empty `BytesIO` object:

```
pdfrw.PdfWriter.write(new_bytes_object, filled_pdf)
# I'm not sure about the syntax, I haven't used this lib before
```

This works because `io.BytesIO` objects act like a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), also known as a file-like object. It and related classes like `io.StringIO` behave like files in memory, such as the object `f` created with the built-in function [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) below:

```
with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(some_data)
```

Before you attempt to read from `new_bytes_object`, don't forget to `seek(0)` back to the beginning, or rewind it. Otherwise, the object seems empty.

```
new_bytes_object.seek(0)
```