# Download video audio from URL into numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I want to do as the title says, from a video url, get the audio and have it available as a numpy array.

Can't find any library/procedure that does both, they either download the audio and save it into an mp3/wav file or load an audio file into a numpy array.

I want to skip the "saving" part, and just have it available as a numpy array in execution time

Comment: Download the audio and save it as an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object, which you can then load directly into a Numpy array. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68985992/1426065).

Comment: a library which does both will not necessarily be more resource efficient than you writing code to perform the underlying actions in your own code